# Java CORBA Client Disconnects When Event Fires

Tags: java, corba

I have built a Java CORBA application that subscribes to an event server.  The application narrows and logs on just fine, but as soon as an event is sent to the client, it breaks with the error below.  Please advise.

```
2010/04/25!13.00.00!E00555!enserver!EventServiceIF_i.cpp!655!PID(7390)!enserver - e._info=system exception, ID 'IDL:omg.org/CORBA/TRANSIENT:1.0'
TAO exception, minor code = 54410093 (invocation connect failed; ECONNRESET), completed = NO
```

EDIT:
Please note, this only happens when running on some machines.  It works on some, but not others.  Even on the same platform (I've tried Windows XP/7 and CentOS linux)  Some work, some don't...

Here is the WireShark output...looks like the working PC is much more interactive with the network compared to the non-working PC.
**Working PC**

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
     62 28.837255   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50169 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
     63 28.907068   fe80::5de0:8d21:937e:c649 ff02::1:3             LLMNR    Standard query A isatap
     64 28.907166   10.10.10.209          224.0.0.252           LLMNR    Standard query A isatap
     65 29.107259   10.10.10.209          10.255.255.255        NBNS     Name query NB ISATAP<00>
     66 29.227000   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TCP      23120 > 50169 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=32768 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=0
     67 29.227032   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50169 > 23120 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
     68 29.238063   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Request s=326 id=5 (two-way): op=logon
     69 29.291765   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Reply s=420 id=5: No Exception
     70 29.301395   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Request s=369 id=6 (two-way): op=registerEventStat
     71 29.348275   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          GIOP     GIOP 1.1 Reply s=60 id=6: No Exception
     72 29.405250   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50170 > telnet [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
     73 29.446055   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TCP      telnet > 50170 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=32768 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=0
     74 29.446128   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50170 > telnet [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=66560 Len=0
     75 29.452021   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TELNET   Telnet Data ...
     76 29.483537   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TELNET   Telnet Data ...
     77 29.483651   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TELNET   Telnet Data ...
     78 29.523463   10.10.10.250          10.10.10.209          TCP      telnet > 50170 [ACK] Seq=4 Ack=5 Win=32768 Len=0
     79 29.554954   10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      50169 > 23120 [ACK] Seq=720 Ack=505 Win=66048 Len=0
```

**Non-working PC**

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Info
      1 0.000000    10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      64161 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
      2 2.999847    10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      64161 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260 WS=8
      3 4.540773    Cisco_3c:78:00        Cisco-Li_55:87:72     ARP      Who has 10.0.0.1?  Tell 10.10.10.209
      4 4.540843    Cisco-Li_55:87:72     Cisco_3c:78:00        ARP      10.0.0.1 is at 00:1a:70:55:87:72
      5 8.992284    10.10.10.209          10.10.10.250          TCP      64161 > 23120 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1260
```

Comment: I couldn't agree more.  My forehead is bleeding from banging it on the CORBA wall

Answer (score 0):

Benny are your still suffering under the yoke of corba?

If so the following may help:

- Are you able to find out what version of TAO the server is running?
- Have your tried it with Sun's orb (long shot)?
- You could give [OpenORB](http://openorb.sourceforge.net/) a try.
- Failing all of the above and if you have python knowledge can you access the server with omniORBpy?

If none of the above works then I am unsure but let me know I can probably come up with a few more ideas. The version of TAO that the server is using would be helpful, at least then you can get an idea of the corba specification version you are dealing with.

Comment: I actually did end up using omniORBpy and I'm having the same (or similar) problem.  I am trying it on linux with python, but please see my other post for more info.  I would reward both posts if you were able to help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418446/corba-event-client-etimedout

Answer (score 0):

Does both client and server running inside the same LAN? I mean is there any firewall or software firewall enabled on your client machine?  Or between client and server?

Comment: They both are on the same LAN.  I have even tried turning off the Windows firewall on a few tests for the machines that don't work and no success.

Comment: Could you please use wireshark/tcpdump to capture the TCP/IP traffic flow? it might be much more helpful for troubleshooting.